# How to execute a shortcut with space in the target field from the command line?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, dynamics-gp

For example, I am trying to execute a Dynamics GP shortcut icon from the command line.

Target is as follows:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2018\Dynamics.exe" Dynamics.set**

What is the command to execute the following shortcut through Windows command line without double clicking on the shortcut icon in order to open it?

Comment: What do you mean by command? That is the command

Comment: What I mean is how do I open the shortcut through the command line without double clicking the icon that is on my Desktop. The Target value it has when I view the shortcut property is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2018\Dynamics.exe" Dynamics.set

Comment: What happens when you copy that to the command line and hit enter?

Comment: It displays "The system cannot find the path specified."

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2015\Dynamics.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GP2015\Dynamics.set"

It took me a few tries to do it, but that worked